# Problemas con el envio de un XML a un servicio de prueba Python ¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Tags: python, xml, post, servicio

Estoy iniciándome en la programación en Python, y me surgió un inconveniente al intentar enviar un XML a un servicio, también realizado en Python. 
Básicamente levanto el servicio y luego trato de hacer el envío, pero al ejecutar el envío no se genera ningún tipo de respuesta.
Les paso a continuación el código de ambos archivos:

Servicio.py

```
from flask import Flask
import urllib2
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])     
def main():

 return ("Hello there!")
if __name__ == "__main__": 
   app.run(debug=True)
```

envioXML.py

```
import httplib
import xml.dom.minidom

HOST = "localhost:5000/"
API_URL = "/api/url"


def do_request(xml_location):
    """HTTP XML Post request"""
    request = open('X:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx.xml', "r").read()
    print ("Control 1")
    webservice = httplib.HTTP(HOST)
    webservice.putrequest("POST", API_URL)
    webservice.putheader("Host", HOST)
    webservice.putheader("User-Agent", "Python post")
    webservice.putheader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"")
    webservice.putheader("Content-length", "%d" % len(request))
    webservice.endheaders()

    webservice.send(request)
    print ("Control 2")
    statuscode, statusmessage, header = webservice.getreply()

    result = webservice.getfile().read()
    resultxml = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(result)

    print (statuscode, statusmessage, header)
    print (resultxml.toprettyxml())

    with open("output-%s" % xml_location, "w") as xmlfile:
       xmlfile.write(resultxml.toprettyxml())
       print ("Control 3")

do_request("xml-request-file.xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

A ver si puedo ayudarte un poco. Lo primero te recomendaría que especificases la versión de Python que estás utilizando. Porque muchas veces puede cambiar la manera que se usa ciertas librerías.
Viendo que usas 'httplib' he pensado que Python2.7.

Conociendo la versión de Python vamos por partes:

1. La ruta: En el Flask solo tienes como punto de entrada POST y GET la ruta "/" ("localhost:5000/"). Pero luego en el script de envioXML haces el POST contra "localhost:5000/api/url". La solución es usar la misma ruta en ambos lados.
2. Otro error es 'HOST = "localhost:5000/"'. La barra del final no puedes ponerla en el HOST, porque entiende que el puerto no es numérico. La ruta en tu script la especificas en API_URL.
3. También veo, que en la función "do_request('xml-request-file.xml')", le pasas la ruta del fichero xml, pero luego no la usas, sino que tiras de otra ruta puesta a mano. Con que se la pases al llamar a la función ya vale.
4. Y por último, pero muy importante, tanto el fichero que envías al servicio, como las respuesta del servicio, deben ser XML válidos. Te dejo el código de cómo lo he solucionado.

Servicio.py

```
from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/api/url", methods=['GET','POST'])  
def main():
    xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><breakfast_menu><food><name>Belgian Waffles</name><calories>650</calories></food></breakfast_menu>'
    return Response(xml, mimetype='text/xml')

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

envioXML.py

```
import httplib
import xml.dom.minidom

HOST = "localhost:5000"
API_URL = "/api/url"


def do_request(xml_location):
    """HTTP XML Post request"""
    request = open(xml_location, "r").read()
    print ("Control 1")
    webservice = httplib.HTTP(HOST)
    webservice.putrequest("POST", API_URL)
    webservice.putheader("Host", HOST)
    webservice.putheader("User-Agent", "Python post")
    webservice.putheader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"")
    webservice.putheader("Content-length", "%d" % len(request))
    webservice.endheaders()

    webservice.send(request)
    print ("Control 2")
    statuscode, statusmessage, header = webservice.getreply()
    print(statuscode, statusmessage, header)

    result = webservice.getfile().read()
    resultxml = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(result)

    print (statuscode, statusmessage, header)
    print (resultxml.toprettyxml())

    with open("output-%s" % xml_location, "w") as xmlfile:
    xmlfile.write(resultxml.toprettyxml())
    print ("Control 3")

do_request("xml-request-file.xml")
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Si es así, por favor puntúa. ˆˆ